# Instrumental Played in Episode 92 DBS

Tags: music, dragon-ball-super

Can anyone tell me about the instrumental played in Episode 92 of Dragon Ball Super after 19:05 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the soundtrack - A Mother's Love, by Norihito Sumitomo, Dragon Ball Super Original Soundtrack Vol.2, DISC 1. :)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m1nbGqkJJgM

Answer (score 0):

15 min searching, the closest thing I could find is "A Break in the Battle".

Here's the YouTube link for the piano cover: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQYoYYLFs3o

Comment: Thanks for your time but it is not the same. you can listen from https://youtu.be/OJS8ZgGRH94    at keyframe 0:52 onwards.

Answer (score -1):

After searching so long, I finally found it is Mirai Bulma's Theme.

YouTube link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c5fKlMGuV8o (piano version)